# Convert negative integer to positive using VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, integer

How to convert negative integer to positive integer using vb.net ? Also if there is a function in SQL Server 2008 to do the same concept ?

Comment: Why have you changed the accepted answer months after the fact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Abs()` in ***SQL Server*** and `Math.Abs()` in ***VB.NET***

Answer (score 13):

In .NET, use [`Math.Abs()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2yzeea2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

In TSQL, use [`ABS()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189800.aspx)

Answer (score 8):

Regardless of the language you're programming in.  You can multiply any number by -1 to change the number's sign.

```
-5 * -1 = 5
5 * -1 = -5
```